# Objective-C Class / Library to send "curl -F"

Tags: objective-c, curl

I'm looking for some objective-c Curl Library to send a "curl -F ..." command.

I just found complicated ways.. is there an easy class which let me send it easy as direct command?

Greetings

Comment: The question isn't clear. Do you literally want to execute curl as a separate process, or is your goal to send a POST multipart/form-data payload?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like NSTask:

> Using the NSTask class, your program can run another program as a subprocess and can monitor that program’s execution. 
>   [NSTask Class reference](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTask_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Apple gives an example in [Interacting with the Operating System](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/OperatingSystem/Tasks/createtask.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000803-BBCFGGAE). If you find the learning curve there a bit steep, start with the invaluable [Quickies](http://borkware.com/quickies/one?topic=nstask).